# Displaying text according to the ID of category LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
       @foreach($products as $product)
            <tr class="product">
            <td>{{ $product->product_name }}</td>
            <td>${{ $product->price }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->category }}</td> 
            <td>{{ $product->product_description }}</td>
            <td><a href = 'delete/{{ $product->product_id }}'><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a></td>
      @endforeach
```

Hi, how do program this code such that if the catagory_id = 1 "Sushi" is displayed and if catagory_id = 2 "Drinks" is displayed.

As of now this is the display:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YWHf.png)

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsk1G.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your problem first you need to fetch all the associate category.. 
You can do it with eager loading .. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading
Then you need to check the category condition..

```
$products = App\PRODUCTMODELNAME::with('category')->get();
 @foreach($products as $product)
    <tr class="product">
    <td>{{ $product->product_name }}</td>
    <td>${{ $product->price }}</td>
    <td>
     @if($product->category->id  === 1)
        Sushi
     @elseif($product->category->id  === 1)
        Drinks
    </td> 
    <td>{{ $product->product_description }}</td>
    <td><a href = 'delete/{{ $product->product_id }}'><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a></td>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this

*In Product Model*

```
public function category() 
{
   return $this->belongTo(Category::class);
}
```

In Ctonroller

```
$products = Product::with('category')->paginate()
```

In Blade

```
@foreach($products as $product)
       <tr class="product">
       <td>{{ $product->product_name }}</td>
       <td>${{ $product->price }}</td>
       <td>{{ $product->category->name }}</td> 
       <td>{{ $product->product_description }}</td>
       <td><a href = 'delete/{{ $product->product_id }}'><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a></td>
 @endforeach
```